# writing data structure to a file

Tags: c

I know following approach may not be portable but that is exactly what I want to find out now.
Imagine I have some data structure

```
struct student
{
    char name[20];
    int age;
} x;
```

Now I want to write it to a file like this:

```
fwrite(&x, sizeof(student), 1, filePointer);
```

Read similarly:

```
fread(voidPointer, sizeof(student), 1, filePointer);
// Now possibly do a memcpy
memcpy(studentObjectPointer, voidPointer, sizeof(student));
```

**My question is**: Say I don't want to copy this file to another computer, and I will read it from the same computer that created this file.
Will the portability (endianness, packed data structure) issues still apply to above approach? Or it will work fine?

Comment: Look portable enough to me. 'packed' is not portable and you do not need it. GNU certainly doesn't. Microsoft sometimes do. If your own your own computer,endianness and structure padding is not a problem. What you write is what you read.

Comment: don't forget to open the file in binary mode, `fopen("filename","wb")`

Comment: Portability problems can occur if 1) the processor is different or 2) the compiler is different or 3) the compiler options dealing with alignment are different.  You should only do this if your programs compiled with the same compiler for one machine.

Comment: @Gene: if that's not the case, I should probably consider other option right? (or maybe separately write data - like write int separately, write string separately and separately read them back). This way I don't have to bother about packed issues right? I could take care of endianness. Only issue would remain like if int is of different size on another machine?

Comment: IMO yes.  If this is a serious system, you should look at serious serialization.  A library like this one http://s11n.net/c11n/ might be the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

If the file would be copied on other machines, you will have to build your own *serializer* and *deserializer*. With the structure you gave it is quite simple.

You have to define which endianness to adopt when writing numbers (here, the `int age`).
Here, you could process like this :

1. Open the file in binary mode
2. Write the 20 bytes of the `name` string
3. Write the `age` in a *CHOSEN* endianness (big endian)

When reading it back, you will certainly have to convert the Big-Endianness to the local endianness of the machine.

There is still a remaining issue : if `sizeof (int)` is not the same between the two machines. In that case things get more vicious and I think the above is not sufficient.
If you really need to be portable across a wide range of machines, consider the use of specific length types defined in `#include <stdint.h>` such as `int32_t` for instance.

Answer (score 0):

Remember, we're living in a 4-dimension world. You said, the saved file will not move in the x, y and z axis, it will be used on the same computer. But you did not mentioned the 4th dimension, the time. If the structure changes, it will fail.

At least, you should put a signature field in the structure. Fill it with a constant value before write(), check it right after read(), and change the constant value when the structure gets modified.